# Google analytic's on submit push

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

So someone from my class came to me with a question saying they are for word for word doing what the teacher asked but the the result they are looking for isn't happening. Just some simple code... but the course that she doing is older so I'm unsure if the code the teacher is use is out date or just wrong.

Basically when the user clicks the button a event is suppose to be pushed but isn't. I don't know what to say and they ain't getting the answer they are looking for. Is onsubmit="_gaq.push()" still the right way to do it?

```
<body>
<h2>Get our Newsletter!</h2>

<form method="post" action="newsletter.php"> 
 <div> 
Name:
<br />
<input type="text" name="name" value="" size="30" /> <br />
<br />
Email:<br />
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="30" /> <br />
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="message" value="success" />
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up Now!" class="submit"   onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/virtual/submit/']);" /> <br />
<br />
</div> 
</form>

</body>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-74879630-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The `_gaq` was the old `ga.js` module, which is now deprecated. It seems that you are loading in the new `analytics.js` library, which uses another API to send events.

So you'd want to change your code to use the [new API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events):

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up Now!" class="submit" onsubmit="ga('send', 'pageview', '/virtual/submit/');" />
```

Note that your analytics code might not succeed before the form submits. If you'd want to be sure the event gets tracked, you should delay the form submit with JavaScript to hold until the event gets tracked.

Comment: Thanks you that's what I was thinking and expecting. The source code was from around the 2012-2013 year so at least I can tell them and point them in the right direction and documents to review... and not use the older legacy library.